# Preview and Resizing in Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, preview, xcode6.3

I am using `Xcode 6.3`, but I am not able get `preview and Resizing` button. The resizing button should be present at last in the attached image.

There is 4 buttons in this panel before `xcode 6.3`

[image]

I am not able to see the last button of the following image:

[image]

So how can achieve that 4th button?

Comment: Bhavin, I have edited my question.

Comment: there is no option of resizing in 6.3

Comment: How can I achieve this?

Comment: How can I check my added constraints in app screen for auto layout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76890/discussion-between-bhavin-and-amit-raj).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok there is no option Preview and Resize in xcode 6.3....

If you want to check constraints then the option is `Document outline` and  for preview .... just check below..

first select show assistant editor....the left and right panel shows controllers....

[image]

and now follow this image

[image]

Comment: Bhavin, How did you make this image? Can you please tell me.