# How to simulate different size iPhones in the same time?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

Looks like the iPhone simulator came with xcode can only simulate one device each time. Is there anyway I can simulate different devices in the same time?

Comment: check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030591/preview-and-resizing-in-xcode-6-3/30031163#30031163

Answer (score 2):

You can't simulate multiple devices simultaneously. But if you're just trying to look at your storyboard/xib layouts at different sizes, you can add multiple devices to Xcode's preview assistant.  See [“Previewing Your Layout for Different Localizations, iOS Devices, and iOS Versions”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/PreviewingLayouts.html) for details.

Comment: I know this method. However, I am not using stroyboard/xib. I create all the views programmatically, so I can't see the layouts in the preview assistant.